# Spring CORS Filter for Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-chrome, cors, private-network-access

I have a webapp hosted on a public URL, trying to call a local webservice API (running on localhost)
I am using Chrome to access the public website, this creates a CORS issue as described here

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/

The solution stated in the above link is to either,

1. Disable Private Network Access checks in Chrome (which works)
2. Set response header "Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true"  (doesnt work)

There is no Spring CORS support for the header "Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network" yet. So I have tried various ways to create a filter in my Spring Boot application, but to no avail. The filter never gets invoked and I encounter the CORS issue.

Please point me in the right direction to fix this issue.

This is my filter class

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("MyFilter invoked............");
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

This is my config class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsMappingConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite an answer to why your code does not work, but I have just created a Spring way to achieve this, so it may assist you. I am using Spring Boot 2.7 therefore Spring 5.3 is included.

It uses a custom `CorsProcessor` class to add the relevant header to the response.

`CustomCorsProcessor.java`:

```
public class CustomCorsProcessor extends DefaultCorsProcessor implements CorsProcessor {

    private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_PRIVATE_NETWORK = "Access-Control-Request-Private-Network";
    private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NETWORK = "Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network";
    
    @Override
    public boolean processRequest(@Nullable CorsConfiguration config, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        
        //Allow DefaultCorsProcessor to run first
        boolean superResult = super.processRequest(config, request, response);
        if (superResult == false) return false;
        
        ServerHttpRequest serverRequest = new ServletServerHttpRequest(request);
        
        //If the CORS header requesting Private Network access is present, respond allowing access
        if(serverRequest.getHeaders().containsKey(ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_PRIVATE_NETWORK)) {
            response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NETWORK, Boolean.toString(true));
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

You might like to customise the `CorsConfiguration` class to avoid hardcoding the Boolean `true`.

Then the `CustomCorsProcessor` class is used in `WebSecurityConfig` as a `CorsProcessor`.

Note that before this Private Network change, the `CorsConfigurationSource` was itself an `@Bean` but now the `CorsFilter` is the `@Bean`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsFilter
            .cors()
            .and()
            ... as needed for your application

        return http.build();
    }

    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://domain1.com");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource = corsConfigurationSource();
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource);

        //Register our custom CorsProcessor that includes the Private Network allowed header
        corsFilter.setCorsProcessor(new CustomCorsProcessor());
        return corsFilter;
    }
}
```

This then allowed Chrome to connect to the Private Network web service.

This is partly based on what I found from these URLs:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: I couldn't make this work. I have an updated Chrome Version 113.0.5672.64 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Spring-boot 2.7 as well. Also, in the Chrome flags I tried enabling "Respect the result of Private Network Access preflights", but it didn't help. In your response, should SecurityFilterChain be a bean?

Comment: Apologies, yes it should be an `@Bean`, I've edited that above. I was testing with Chrome 112 with the same 'Respect the result' flag on. Of course my config is somewhat more complicated and proprietary but I hope I've captured the relevant bits. Check in the Chrome Dev Tools Network panel: is the `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network` header being sent? Can you Debug into the `CustomCorsProcessor.processRequest()` method - does it run?

Comment: Thanks for response, I cant debug into `CustomCorsProcessor.processRequest()` (its not called) so I cant check the `Control-Request-Private-Network` header. My Chrome Console gives this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://....' from origin 'http://.... ' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local. ` 
The only solution working for me is to `Block insecure private network requests.` under Chrome flags, but this I what I wanted to avoid in first place.

Comment: Also I dont see the `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network` header under Chrome Network panel. It has the warning `Provisional headers are shown`. I tried disabling the cache as well to avoid caching the preflight.

Comment: I am running my Dev environment with HTTPS and therefore it is 'secure', even though it's a self-signed cert. That might be part of the issue (my Chrome has 'block insecure private network requests' as 'default').

Comment: To get around any potential Chrome/insecure issue, you could also try making the 'preflight' request in something like Postman or Insomnia. I set my request up as an `OPTIONS` request, adding an `origin` header and a variety of `Access-Control-*` headers, including: `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network` : `true`. After that I could see the response containing `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network` : `true`.

Comment: Yes an OPTIONS request in postman does get handled in my local webservice, just not from Chrome. I just realized, my request was a HTTP GET and so was considered as a simple request and no preflight was triggered (yet its blocked by Chrome). I introduced a custom header to force it as a non-simple request, so now I can see the preflight. But the preflight fails with ERR_FAILED and what is strange is in Chrome network tab, the GET is shown BEFORE the preflight !

Comment: Is is possible my `default` in Chrome flag `Block insecure private network requests` is different from your `default`?

Comment: Hi @bdev, apologies I have been on leave and then not back to StackOverflow for some time. I can't really be sure, but I believe my `block insecure private network requests` `default` means `enabled`.

Comment: I really believe that your best step would be to add HTTPS to your localhost webservice, and the public service if it doesn't have it already. See: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/#accessing-private-ip-addresses . If you can get any 'insecure' issue out of the way, you can then see if the 'Private Network Access' part does work correctly.

Comment: For my Spring Boot application, adding HTTPS was a matter of creating a Keystore and setting `server.ssl.*` properties, see sections 2 & 3 of: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate for the details.

Comment: you are right, adding HTTPS to both did fix the issue :) Strange that having both on HTTP was creating this problem. Thank you for all the support!

Comment: No problem, great to hear it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is now support for private area network CORS in Spring: use `allowPrivateNetwork` method of `CorsRegistry`, for example, like this:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addMapping("/**")
        .allowedMethods(
            Stream.of(
                    HttpMethod.HEAD,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    HttpMethod.PUT,
                    HttpMethod.DELETE,
                    HttpMethod.PATCH)
                .map(HttpMethod::name)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .allowPrivateNetwork(true)
        .allowedHeaders(
            HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,
            HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
            HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,
            HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
  }
}
```